# iot.listDimensions is not a function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am using AWS. IoT Javascript SDK to try and call the "listDimensions" function. I am referring to [Class: AWS.Iot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html) documentation.

Whenever I'm attempting to call this function I get the error "iot.listDimensions is not a function".

I am referring to [listDimensions-property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#listDimensions-property)

Here is the code I'm trying to get working:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const iot = new AWS.Iot({apiVersion: '2015-05-28'});

async function getDimensions() {
    const dimensions = await iot.listDimensions({}).promise();
    return dimensions;
}
```

I have tried running code for other methods found in the docs and those seem to be working fine.

Is it possible the documentation is out of date, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have a recent release of the AWS-SDK as the Dimensions functions were added relatively recently to the Javascript API (beginning of April 2020).

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#26510

> **2.651.0**
>
> feature: Iot: This release introduces Dimensions for AWS IoT Device Defender. Dimensions can be used in Security Profiles to collect and monitor fine-grained metrics.

Comment: Thank you that did it! Guess I gotta be a bit better at checking the changelog next time